# AWS SDK for PHP not reading credentials from ~/.aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm installing the AWS SDK for PHP.  This [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/file-location.html) mentions that the config and credential files should be located in '~/.aws' which in on my server is actually '/root/.aws'.  So I did just that and tried to upload a test file to S3 with code that I know works, see below.  I got the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)...
```

It works perfectly if I add my credentials to '/home/mysite/.aws' but that isn't an ideal workaround because the AWS credentials will be part of the daily user backup.  In any case the credentials shouldn't be anywhere near the user's directory.  How do I get the SDK to read the credentials in '~/.aws'?  I experimented with permissions, changing from 600 to 644 but still the same issue.

```
require ('/home/mysite/public_html/lib/composer/vendor/autoload.php');
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$file = '/home/mysite/public_html/images/christmas.jpg';

$sharedConfig = [
'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
];

// Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);
// Create an Amazon S3 client using the shared configuration data.
$client = $sdk->createS3();

$result = $client->putObject([
 'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
  'Key'    => 'full/christmas.jpg',
  'CacheControl' => 'max-age=31536000',
  'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
  'SourceFile' => $file,
  'ACL' => 'public-read',
]);
```

Comment: _"It works perfectly if I add my credentials to '/home/mysite/.aws'"_ This means that your web server process is running under the `mysite` user -- which is how it should be configured, not as root. It's working as intended. _"In any case the credentials shouldn't be anywhere near the user's directory."_ That's exactly where they belong. Maybe update your backup script to exclude the file? Or update it to only include `public_html`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Well I certainly could exclude the file in the backup.  Thanks for confirming how this shoudl work.  I'm astonished that we're expected to add credentials to a user's directory even if it's outside the document root.  To me that's a big red flag and a major security flaw.  Well I suppose it is slightly better than hard-coding credentials into code...

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think it's a major security flaw. Where else should a user's credentials go, if not their own home directory? If you put them in root then you need to give the user root access to adjust their own credentials, and you can support only one user. Putting your libraries and other non-public code under public_html is a bigger issue.

Comment: Where is this code being run? If it's something like an EC2 instance you should be using [Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) which handles all the credentials stuff for you.

Comment: You can `echo $AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` to see which file path it is referring to and then change the location as per your convenience.